# Tomcat hangs after GWT app starts

Tags: tomcat, gwt

We are running GWT 2.5.1, Tomcat 7 (latest release) on windows server 2008, reasonably up to date IE, configured to server web pages over SSL.

The user can run the web-app and it will happily run until the user closes the web-browser, or logs out from the app.

However, immediately after starting the web-app, the tomcat home page becomes unresponsive, and after the user has logged out or restarted the browser, the web-app does not respond.

The only way to recover is to restart tomcat.

If we run tomcat in non-SSL mode, there is no problem.

**EDIT**

The server.xml file appears to be pretty standard, with the SSL connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="<file>" keystorePass="<pw>"/>
```

If we try dumping the threads, all we get is a "Console CTRL+BREAK event signaled" message in the logfile.

The following are partial logs from Tomcat. As you can see, once we start the web-app, everything goes completely silent.

**stdout**

```
16:13:57,936 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:13:57,936 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:13:57,951 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5528416b - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2015-11-18 16:13:57,951 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 clearcoreauth - Starting session listener.
2015-11-18 16:13:57,967 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 clearcorexuafilter - Method call: init
2015-11-18 16:13:57,967 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 clearcorexuafilter - Method exit: init
```

**catalina**

```
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
...
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7.0.65\webapps\manager
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7.0.65\webapps\manager has finished in 110 ms
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7.0.65\webapps\ROOT
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_Tomcat7.0.65\webapps\ROOT has finished in 78 ms
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443"]
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 18, 2015 4:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8068 ms
```

**localhost_access_log**

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:00 +0000] "GET /clearcore/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 3438
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:00 +0000] "GET /clearcore/images/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 808
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:00 +0000] "GET /clearcore/spinner.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1118
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:00 +0000] "GET /clearcore/defaultlogin.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1504
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:08 +0000] "GET /clearcore/images/sprites.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7111
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:12 +0000] "POST /clearcore/ClearCore/Login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:12 +0000] "GET /clearcore/index.jsp;jsessionid=05FF9853857C40F9E0B3198B3E55DC3A HTTP/1.1" 200 2374
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:12 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore.css HTTP/1.1" 200 10967
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:12 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/ClearCore.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6004
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:12 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/gwt/clean/clean.css HTTP/1.1" 200 29325
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:13 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/E60ECA106C49CC447903262AD44A210E.cache.html HTTP/1.1" 200 823732
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:14 +0000] "POST /clearcore/ClearCore/CCService HTTP/1.1" 200 819
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:14 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 43
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:15 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/deferredjs/E60ECA106C49CC447903262AD44A210E/2.cache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 484
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:15 +0000] "GET /clearcore/images/lblgrad2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 197
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:15 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/gwt/clean/images/thumb_vertical.png HTTP/1.1" 200 231
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:15 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/gwt/clean/images/hborder.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1995
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:15 +0000] "GET /clearcore/ClearCore/deferredjs/E60ECA106C49CC447903262AD44A210E/1.cache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1331282
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Nov/2015:16:13:16 +0000] "POST /clearcore/ClearCore/CCService HTTP/1.1" 200 335
```

**EDIT 2**

Having managed to get a complete log, including shut down, we are now getting the following in the catalina / stderr logs. We do not get this output in working systems.

This strongly suggests that for some reason, the thread [Thread-3] and
[MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] are hanging. Can anyone suggest where I should look to try to find the reason?

```
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] appears to have started a thread named [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@552e705d]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@5bd3155b]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1@7f1f3875]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@5ab3ca86]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1@51b551ef]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@57164bd1]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@552e705d]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@78cbb301]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1@51b551ef]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@555449c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1@7f1f3875]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@210b6080]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@552e705d]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@71ec8472]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1@7f1f3875]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@5eeb92cc]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1@3bf2bfc3]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@3e0bb9f4]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/clearcore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1@51b551ef]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@73dd61fe]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8443"]
Nov 18, 2015 5:41:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: Can you show the `server.xml` of your tomcat? Any relevant messages in `catalina.out` or other log files? Also you could try to use the tomcat thread dump feature to see what your threads are doing. Right-click on the Tomcat Properties icon and select 'Thread Dump' from the options. This will output a thread dump to one of the log files in your tomcat\logs directory.